# Migrating string to Sharepoint Online in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, url, query-string

I moved a workflow to our Sharepoint Online enviroment from on prem. I am having  a hard time figuring out the correct format for the URL string.

The first image is the original string

The second is my attempt at migrating it, but I do not think it is correct.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The only thing that looks wrong is the Source parameter

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: it doesn't match your new site url, its like `http://cisp1/departments/accounting...`

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you migrated the workflow, please state the steps. The easiest way would be opening the workflow with designer and select the "Save as Template" option from the ribbon and then you can redeploy your workflows wherever you want(If you have the exact libraries/Lists). Next way is to copy the entire action from the On prem Workflow and create a new workflow for the list which is in online with the same name, then paste the steps(Adjust/modify the field names accordingly).

Comment: I saved as template, then have been started adjusting the steps as necessary to the Online sections.

Comment: @TravisEaston apologies for the late reply, so did it helped and solved your problem?

Comment: No, I am still reaching the section above in the workflow, when I hit approve on sharepoint it does not set it to approved, it goes to the else statement for reject and CCing the Manager no matter what. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @TravisEaston hope the issue is resolved , else please do share the workflow steps with me. Ill check and guide you through(The entire steps not the string builder).